# WSSecurity IBM DataPower issues with WCF client

Tags: wcf, web-services, interop, x509certificate, ibm-datapower

I'm trying to consume an IBM DataPower  web service in WCF getting the following error message:

**Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.**

The HTTP response is coming back as 200 and I can see the correct SOAP response while debugging it in Fiddler.

However, the WCF clients doesn't seem to know how to process the BinarySecurityToken element in the SOAP response.

Here is my WCF config:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxx:6443/xxxx/xxxxx"

  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"

  contract="SoapPort" name="XXSoapPort" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
      </endpoint>
    </client>

<customBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" />
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />

          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
</customBinding>

 <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="xxxxxx"   storeLocation="LocalMachine"  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"  storeName="My"  />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```

This is a SOAP request sample:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dgi="http://dgi.gub.uy" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-
1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-45851B081998E431E8132880700036719"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-
1.0.xsd">binarysecuritytoken base64...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="Signature-13"
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-14">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>62KaCXQkeXTGyGd+aoX46cGAl9M=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
YdwY0hmkHE8tnQmGQBdfA5fjVyoHWMiQhKanI1SEaii295hakwMbf5KsP3YMMhzl4HEHs6nqhZpq
lyL1OBcbJPJQN34uhOtucnzgObUYHckkJqfAN/sYmfNMSFGDvyZCFQSiJwh8dkvKxmxzdUwv3wza
M+i0nzLAh9viQZYS8N8=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-45851B081998E431E8132880700036720">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-45851B081998E431E8132880700036821" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-45851B081998E431E8132880700036719" ValueType="http://docs.oasisopen.
org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-14" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<method>
    data...
    </method>
..
```

This is an SOAP response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAPENC="
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0477b7a-df1a-4883-9ae1-59a518913f96" EncodingType="http://docs.oasisopen.
org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssx509-
token-profile-1.0#X509v3" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-
1.0.xsd">MIIFrDCCA5SgAwIBAgIQas+Rf7PxwFxNudVRjoOzEjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB6MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVWTErMCkGA1UECgwiQURNSU5JU1RSQ
UNJT04gTkFDSU9OQUwgREUgQ09SUkVPUzEfMB0GA1UECwwWU0VSVklDSU9TIEVMRUNUUk9OSUNPUzEdMBsGA1UEAwwUQ29ycmVvIFVydWd1YXlvIC
0gQ0EwHhcNMTEwNDI4MjEwMDAxWhcNMTIwNDI4MjEwMDAxWjCBxzEiMCAGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYTam1vbnRhbmVAZGdpLmd1Yi51eTEfMB0GA1UECwwW
QU5BTElTSVMgREUgUFJPRFVDQ0lPTjEhMB8GA1UECgwYREdJLVBSVUVCQSBTRVJWSUNJT1MgV0VCMRMwEQYDVQQIDApNb250ZXZpZGVvMQswCQ
YDVQQGEwJVWTEYMBYGA1UEBRMPUlVDMjE5OTk5ODIwMDEzMSEwHwYDVQQDDBhER0ktUFJVRUJBIFNFUlZJQ0lPUyBXRUIwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQE
BBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAMcMcu70s0RQkD6ifYBGXwATovTxxA/Hjc8WKM16yJkz63d0eSTjjREYmM87g6NRacADy9LZRyENiRPjsBI+Tw9PHR/7g+frTIS+vIQZ0+f
9Rq1q2uxvw8TKoO9FvcrBabdl9dUBIrJEPa20wj6U+dupTZ66bD5uFXBUsKo2sZujAgMBAAGjggFiMIIBXjAeBgNVHREEFzAVgRNqbW9udGFuZUBkZ2kuZ3ViLnV
5MAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgP4MB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMCBggrBgEFBQcDBDARBglghkgBhvhCAQEEBAMCBaAw
HQYDVR0OBBYEFP0YQfFQvej6szyGhKlpNI0tESi5MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFCWP30Mvjmq6C75GXFdQk7dRvvzZMFQGA1UdIARNMEswSQYMKwYBBAGB9U8
BAQEEMDkwNwYIKwYBBQUHAgEWK2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuY29ycmVvLmNvbS51eS9jb3JyZW9jZXJ0L2Nwcy5wZGYwGAYNKwYBBAGB9U8BAQEEAQQHDAVE
aXNjbzA8BgNVHR8ENTAzMDGgL6AthitodHRwOi8vd3d3LmNvcnJlby5jb20udXkvQ29ycmVvQ2VydC9hbmMuY3JsMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4ICAQA01MEJ
sZ8VXJIybZQ0NlBJPXz7n8GbTf41Aq4lWxLI5rBWJD1uyWUdz2jUD0DuqflTAGknphzxn49QACCTA1Pv0aZ6hnK04uI9j7UJe4LiVx3aWbpLRBCnYrIs+QU2pyClEM
4bNPt0BU2DG+Q9k9SeCDQ8VD7hiD2W/aK8HLo6EVLAEwrl3pTums2dwxtO1KKPw6OBbYYitCjR5j6Hy5q1+fMTFXmx0vo+ZYFOl8DVoSp6OQJd2mcaL0CNVWI
9sOYRkJKEoELIJDSnIMKkUqgN2ilg05Dqcl/TDj2I5VfPLXZpnpuQbb6ADjEOtMzlkfe2EFemn0s/+2Hn97h5rtJMcjTuUhh937JZPWnD1XQTxICjS3ql1nSwbnJz9bk8P
N/j8cK4Kw+xipGo7pRxITFKUHmOIXsj05tH3kFWf8htdU/4rIyrvzJ3xUhita78SHaJMALQa4AGxmSxIEvej0+qyrxx4geMkzb/n5t3JAAluxW2ja3f/FrXMuwT7iKebreMS4
4FO0maMpP29SW94G8yClumghtU/6LI67oHxhpUNkCQ3UV4JaI6wEZcgV5KLXm9rr1i/hMKV5FspQcYg36qdeRz/N4DwuorVwZuTsXCIMwcKQCkzu1oUSkvO3PE
5cCRnu9cyJ3GzPfUO0T8mrCmI2XwISAvkuLs3kd6FeRBAw==</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#Body-75c3e1d7-a956-4387-827e-58e7bf7f9672">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>O+QjV1cBEXJlS3Z15FBQZImx/Gs=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>lCEfQOGBeSvfvHPLUYtT5PUlwe8Gdbv6b2yto4WzSsoEpYz+6d4YFlyt+Vzq1DSK8Jcmz1ELuJkzPwZCt2aAkSxpToI51vjziELJJqiZfGR5gLJRCZ
CK/zhk3pJUBzaiLLSwfN1iX9t4X8IGqisc6yqrS9kabkhUvvsiYrdRIr4=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns="">
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0477b7a-df1a-4883-9ae1-59a518913f96" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="Body-75c3e1d7-a956-4387-827e-58e7bf7f9672" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurityutility-
1.0.xsd">
...data...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "MutualCertificate" instead of "CertificateOverTransport".
This will require you to supply a service certificate - just configure any dummy certificate, even the same one as used for signature. Also you will get an exception on dns expected name which will tell you what to fix.

Then try it once with allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply true and once false.
If this fails send me your config, the soap request you sent, and the response the server sent.

Comment: Yaron, I changed what I told me. It keeps failing. Viewing the log, now seems that the Soap body is encrypted, I do not need to encrypt the data. SOAP request and response samples are on the Question. Do I really need to change from CertificateOverTransport to MutualCertificate?

Comment: Put this attribute on your service contract:

ProtectionLevel=System.Net.ProtectionLevel.Sign

do not revert to cert over trasnport.